# Get last li on a line jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, line

We have a simple `ul`

```
<ul>
   <li>some text</li>
   <li>some some text</li>
   <li>text more</li>
   <li>text here</li>
</ul>

ul { text-align: center; width: 100px; }
li { width: auto; display: inline; }
```

So the `ul` can have several lines. How do I **take last** `li` **of the each line** inside `ul`?

Comment: where's your closing `<ul>`? (and just for clarity `li` stands for "list item")

Comment: @Joseph: I assume it was just a typo, so I've fixed it.

Comment: So, here's your code: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/LLZNQ/. I'm confused, could you explain clearly what you're trying to match? Maybe draw a quick picture?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by *last li on the each line of the ul* you mean the last `li` in each `ul`, then:

```
$('ul li:last-child');
```

However, if you mean that you have your `li`'s within the same `ul` written up on several lines in your source code, and you now want to get the last one on each line, then the answer is that you can't. The DOM does not care about your newline characters in your code.

---

Note: the correct way to do this would be to give those `li`'s a separate class.

```
<ul>
    <li></li><li></li><li class="last"></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li class="last"></li>
    <li></li><li></li><li class="last"></li>
</ul>
```

Now you can use CSS

```css
li.last { color: #444 }
```

and jQuery

```
$('li.last');
```

the proper way...

Comment: The second case, maybe some different hacks can do? Don't care about dom or semantics, it should just work

Comment: @Steve - I'm guessing you could structure your HTML differently if you're trying to find which li's are on different lines.

Answer (score 1):

see [jquery .last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

```
$('ul li').last().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:last` selector - http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

```
$("ul li:last");
```

and if you're trying to find the last `li` for multiple `ul`'s try this:

```
var $lasts = $("ul").map(function(){
    return $(this).find("li:last");
});
```

---

**working example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/SBsqS/

Comment: Kim, what in gods name are you talking about? This is a jQuery selector, not CSS3

Comment: @Kim you can search for almost all questions and find the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This returns group of "last li on the each line of the ul"

```
$("ul li:last");
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the last item in the list using jQuery you can simply use the `last()` method.

See here for more information : http://api.jquery.com/last/

```
var item = $('#myList li').last()
```

Comment: I'm trying to get last li of the **each line**. There can be 5 lines for example, I want to style last li of the end of each line.

Comment: What do you mean by "each line"? There's no such thing as lines in a ul.

Answer (score 0):

```
var theList = document.getElementById('id_of_my_ul');
var theLastItem = theList.childNodes[theList.childNodes.length - 1];
```

Don't know how you would do it in JQuery, but it can't be that dissimilar

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:last` selector: http://api.jquery.com/last-selector