# Is it possible to give a class to last item in each row when using display:inline-block

Tags: jquery

I haven't seen any answers to this , probably because it's not possible, but thought i'd ask anyways.

I have a menu that is dynamically fed its links , so the number of links is constantly changing.  I have the links contained to a fixed width , and use display:inline-block to force them into rows. I am wanting to give the last link in each row a unique class. So need some script possibly to determine the break of the row , if even possible in this scenario ?

```
    <ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li> 
     <li></li> 
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
    </ul>

ul {width:300;}
li{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: What's the connection between `inline-block` and the ability to detect the last `<li>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get last li on a line jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078590/get-last-li-on-a-line-jquery)

Comment: Why do you want to add a class? If you just want to select the last li, try `ul li:last-child`

Comment: @sqren thats the last item, not that last item in a row/line.

Comment: i know css isn't possible , that's why it's tagged for jquery. not familiar enough with jquery to know if possible or not , but wanted to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you mean that because `inline-block` allows each item (in this case the `li`) to wrap within it's parent element, you want to apply css/jquery to the last time on each row.  This is not possible using a simple css/jquery selector.  It's not possible at all with the current version of CSS (CSS3).

With jquery you'll have to loop through each item, and if the top of the item does not match the top of the next item, it is the last item (and the very last item).  However, if your display is responsive, you'll have to execute that jquery method anytime the screen resizes (At worst).

[JsFiddle.Net](http://jsfiddle.net/oymbnL40/)

Html

```
<button>Go</button>
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
    <li>Thirteen</li>
    <li>Fourteen</li>
    <li>Fifteen</li>
    <li>Sixteen</li>
    <li>Seventeen</li>
    <li>Eighteen</li>
    <li>Nineteen</li>
    <li>Twenty</li>
    <li>Twenty One</li>
    <li>Twenty Two</li>
    <li>Twenty Three</li>
    <li>Twenty Four</li>
    <li>Twenty Five</li>
    <li>Twenty Six</li>
    <li>Twenty Seven</li>
    <li>Twenty Eight</li>
    <li>Twenty Nine</li>
    <li>Twenty Ten</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li {display: inline-block;}
.last-li{ text-decoration: underline; }
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        var $li = $('li');
        var top = $li.position().top;
        var $previous = null;

        $li.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.position().top != top)
            {
                top = $this.position().top;
                $previous.addClass('last-li');
            }
            $previous = $this;
        });

        $li.last().addClass('last-li');
    });
});
```

Result

[image: jQuery Last Inline-Block in Row]

**note**

It is possible for weird CSS to break this from working as expected (margins-top etc), just FYI.

Comment: correct Erik , its not responsive so using height of each row would work i think. I don't know jquery/java so possible you can illustrate an example for me to try. Thanks

Comment: Height was wrong, I edited my answer, it should have been **top** of it's [.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/).  Yes I'll add a JsFiddle example shortly.

Comment: I've updated my asnwer.  (I'm not changing the Twenty Ten, I read it while coding and laughed pretty hard).